1 out of many calls to overridden django `Model.save()` generates a pylint `unexpected-keyword-arg` error - how do I satisfy it?
I implemented and have been using this model (super)class I created for years, and it is completely stable on an active site.  I just made a small minor tweak to some completely unrelated portion of its code, and checked my work (on my machine) with the latest superlinter.  Our CI tests on github currently use an old superlinter and it has never complained, so I was surprised to see a linting error on code I haven't touched in years.
My model class has an overridden save() method, which adds a few extra arguments that it pops off kwargs before calling super().save().  I have a number of calls to save inside the class, and the linter is fine with thos extra arguments everywhere else, except in 1 spot (an override of from_db):
@classmethod
def from_db(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    # Instantiate the model object
    rec = super().from_db(*args, **kwargs)

    # If autoupdates are not enabled (i.e. we're not in "lazy" mode)
    if not cls.get_coordinator().are_lazy_updates_enabled():
        return rec

    # Get the field names
    queryset_fields = set(args[1])  # field_names

    # Intersect the queryset fields with the maintained fields
    common_fields = set(cls.get_my_update_fields()).intersection(queryset_fields)

    # Look for maintained field values that are None
    lazy_update_fields = [fld for fld in common_fields if getattr(rec, fld) is None]

    if len(lazy_update_fields) > 0:
        # Trigger a lazy auto-update
        rec.save(fields_to_autoupdate=lazy_update_fields, via_query=True)

    return rec

I tried typehinting rec when it's assigned, but that didn't satisfy the linter.  I figure it's the call to super().from_db() that is setting a type that doesn't include my args... but my save overload is definitely called.
So how do I satisfy pylint here?
ADDENDUM:
Incidentally, I confirmed that the old pylint/superlinter still doesn't complain about the call to save.  I pushed the code despite my local newer superlinter's complaint.
I looked at the base class's from_db method (below).  It's pretty simple.  Perhaps I could just copy the code into my method and not call super().from_db (even though that seems ridiculous)...
@classmethod
def from_db(cls, db, field_names, values):
    if len(values) != len(cls._meta.concrete_fields):
        values_iter = iter(values)
        values = [
            next(values_iter) if f.attname in field_names else DEFERRED
            for f in cls._meta.concrete_fields
        ]
    new = cls(*values)
    new._state.adding = False
    new._state.db = db
    return new

Also: just incidentally, I confirmed via the logs that my save override is correctly called:
[Tue May 28 15:13:35.396716 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648907:tid 2649014] [remote 172.20.202.79:47324] Triggering lazy auto-update of fields: TracerLabel.{name}
[Tue May 28 15:13:35.396755 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 2648907:tid 2649014] [remote 172.20.202.79:47324] Auto-updated TracerLabel.name in TracerLabel.9 using TracerLabel._name from [<empty>] to [13C6].

The Triggering lazy auto-update of fields: ... message is only printed in this method (though I'd removed it from my code above) and the Auto-updated ... message is only ever printed via my .save() override.
So, just to put a fine point on it, that call to save does indeed call my save and passes it the custom arguments.

If you are certain that the linter is wrong here, can't you just # noqa: it? This question is impossible to answer without a MRE.

I don't know that it's technically wrong.  It's effectively wrong, since the code works, but that doesn't mean there isn't a type issue. I would add an ignore.  I've done that before, but it wouldn't look good in the code review. I've gotten complaints about doing that in the past, so I'd prefer to satisfy the linter. Could it be due to the return type hint of the super().from_db() call? Can I cast that or somehow create one of my own model's objects out of it? What's an MRE?

MRE means Minimum Reproducible Example, basically something we could copy/paste and see the error message ourselves.

Right. Just was unfailiar with the abbreviation (other than it being military rations: Meal Ready to Eat), lol. If I have time, I will create an MRE, though I have a deadline fast approaching, so I probably won't get around to it for a couple weeks... I was thinking about it, and I decided I should explicitly confirm that the code actually works as intended, because I couldn't remember if I'd written a test for it. I confirmed it in the web logs. I'll add note to the addendum.

You know what? I think I just got an inspiration on how to maybe quiet pylint here... My save override doesn't explicitly define those keyword args.  It just pops them off kwargs. I bet if I added them to the signature, it might satisfy pylint? But if that's the case, why doesn't it complain about other calls that have different kwargs.  There are more I added than just the 2 in this call. BTW, an MRE would probably just add class MyModel(Model): and the save override def save(*args, **kwargs): kwargs.pop(...) super().save(*args, **kwargs) to the example above.
